# PHP web form to email

Tags: php, html, css, webforms

I have set up an email web form in PHP. The form works correctly and sends the email. but rather than redirecting it comes up with this error: error; you need to submit the form!
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/con17120/public_html/form-to-email.php:5) in /home/con17120/public_html/form-to-email.php on line 70" although the form still works fine it just won't redirect.

.....
Thanks
HTML:

```
     <form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">

    <h1>June/July Crops: </h1>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check1">Pink Lady Apples  2kg <b>$7.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check2">Seedless Imperials Mandarines 1kg <b>$4.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check3">Bananas 1kg <b>$4.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check4">Seedless Thompson Grapes 1kg <b>$6.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check5">Strawberries <b> TBA</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check6">Cherries <b> TBA</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check7">Pistachio Nuts 1/4kg <b>$5.00</b> </h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check8">Cashew Nuts 1/4kg <b>$5.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check9">Tassie Dutch Cream Potatoes 2kg <b>$7.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check10">Avocado's 4 for <b>$7.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check11">Tomatoes 1kg <b>$4.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check12">Cold Pressed Honey 1 kg <b>$11.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check13">Cage Free Eggs 1 Doz <b>$4.00</b></h2>
    <h2><input type="checkbox" class="form cushycms" value="yes" name="check14">Soup Packs <br>(Carrot, parsley, onion, parsnip, celeriac) <b>$4.00</b></h2>
<input class="send" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    <input class="send" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </section>



    <section class="form">
    <h1>Order:</h1>
    <h2 style="margin-top:-15px;">To avoid delays pre-order here. Simply choose your crops, fill in your details below and click submit. </h2><br>

            Full Name:<br>
                <input class="name-email" type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Smith"><br>
            Business:<br>
                <input class="name-email" type="text" name="business" placeholder="Business Inc." ><br>
            Email:<br>
                <input class="name-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="john.appleased@gmail.com"><br>
            Message<br>
                <input class="name-email" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Extra Comments" ><br>


        </form>
```

PHP:

```
//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = '';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Order submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new order from: $name.\n".
    "Email:$email_from: /n"
    "Business Name:  $business.\n".
    "Here is the message: $message\n".
    "PinkLadyApples2kg:$check1\n".
    "Mandarines1kg:$check2\n".
    "Bananas1kg:$check3\n".
    "Grapes1kg:$check4\n".
    "Strawberries:$check5\n".
    "Cherries:$check6\n".
    "PistachioNuts1.4kg:$check7\n".
    "CashewNuts1/4kg:$check8\n".
    "TassieDutchPotatoes2kg:$check9\n".
    "Avocados4:$check10\n".
    "Tomatoes1kg:$check11\n".
    "Honey1doz:$check12\n".
    "Eggs1doz:$check13\n".
    "Soup:$check14\n".

$to = "";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header( 'Location:/thank-you.html' );


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: I think it will be really easier if you show some code :)

Comment: When you don't give your code how can I find what parse error you have done there.

Comment: Should be all edited and updated now. thanks

Comment: FYI: That `.` after `"Soup:$check14\n".` should probably be a `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have header('Location: ....') in your code but you have echo before that or you have something before `<?php` or `<?`. Headers can be send before you output something. You can fix it by removing the echo or using the buffer.

```
<?php
ob_start();

<YOUR CODE>

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Study this link to konw about parse error https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/?src=search. It is basically a syntax error. Where you have forget to use literals like , ; "" ' etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Headers already sent` means that you've tried to use `header()` after PHP has been forced to send the HTTP headers; this usually occurs because some code tried to `echo` something before your call to `header()` (headers must be sent before data).

1. Check the code that runs beforehand for `echo` statements, calls to `print()`, anything that sends output.
2. Check the start of your code file. Does it have spaces or a newline before `<?php`? This would force PHP to send the headers.
3. Check included files for `echo`es, `print()`s, and space before `<?php`. Also check for whitespace and newlines after the included file's `?>`. (This last one is particularly nasty because it's so easy to overlook.)

You can prevent calls to `echo` and `print()` from sending the headers by calling `ob_start()` before the code, and `ob_end_flush()` after it. This will also fix issues with any `?>`s between them. (**Warning:** `ob_end_flush()` sends data, so you *cannot* call `header()` afterwards. The best place to call `ob_end_flush()` is at the end of your code file.)